# SAP and PHP Connection in WAMP server

Tags: php, connection, saprfc

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    include_once ("../libs/sap.php");

    $sap = new SAPConnection();
    // Params:                        hostname   sysnr
    $sap->ConnectToApplicationServer ("hostname", "sysnr");
    // Params:  client username  password  language
    $sap->Open ("client", "username","password","EN");
    $sap->PrintStatus();
    $sap->GetSystemInfo();
    echo "<BR><PRE>"; print_r ($sap); echo ("</PRE>");
    $sap->Close();
?>
```

I have also add the dll in php/ext folder and change the php.ini file accordingly.

DLL files are:

1. php_saprfc_449.dll
2. php_saprfc.dll
3. php_saprfc_528.dll
4. php_saprfc_528_nts.dll
5. php_saprfc_530.dll
6. php_saprfc_530_nts.dll
7. php_sapnwrfc_x86.dll

But I have got the message

> SAPRFC extension is not installed. Exiting....

Please suggest me for the above.

Are any changes required in SAP to enable SAPRFC?

Comment: Check the server error log, there might be a message about failed dll loads.

Comment: Sir, I cant run any thing.The browser showing the above message

Comment: the first googled result from SCN: `On windows you have to make sure that librfc32.dll can be located. You can place this in your C:\windows directory.
The best way I just to install the SAPGui. If librfc32.dll can not be located the extension will not load`